# How to block javascript in c#?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written javascript in aspx file like below

```
  function Validate() {
    try {
        }
     }
```

Now in .aspx.cs file like

```
        ClientScriptManager clientManager = Page.ClientScript;
   clientManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Validate()","Validate()", true);
```

It's not working please help

Comment: Try `clientManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ValidateKey","Validate()", true)`

Comment: Try this is it showing alert in your form?
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "DM", "alert('Hello World');", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
there is need to simply remove the try block then it will work.

**Html page:**

[image]

JavaScript code:

```
function Validate() {

                alert("hello validate(), we are in...");

        }
```

**Server side file:**

[image]

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ClientScriptManager clientManager = Page.ClientScript;
            clientManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Validate()", "Validate()", true);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Plz remove the try{} from your javascript function , or simply replace your javascript function with this one. It will work.

Comment: are you adding server side code in the Page_Load() function? I have test it, after removing try{} from js-function , it is working perfectly. Clear browser's cache and then test.

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?
I have test this code on different pc(s), different visual studio's versions and it's working as required.
This is an executable code, strange if it still not work for you.

Comment: if you were using with try{} block in the js function, it will never work there, so i have removed it from the js function. Is it working now?